# download folder as zip from s3 carrierwave rails heroku

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, amazon-s3, zip, carrierwave

For a rails app using carrierwave and s3

How do you serve a directory as a zip file?
i have

```
/folder/
 file1.png
 file2.png
 file3.png
```

When the user goes to /folder.zip they should be downloading a '.zip' file containing the above directory.

Is this something I need to set up with s3? Is it something carrierwave does? Do I need another gem for this?

Answer (score 1):

A bit late, but I've ran into the same problem.

You might check [Downloading and zipping files that were uploaded to S3 with CarrierWave](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9908571/downloading-and-zipping-files-that-were-uploaded-to-s3-with-carrierwave)